# using nth-child() non recursive?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to use `parent child:nth-child()` and only apply to child's?

The html is the following:

```
<body>
    <div>div 1</div>
    <div>
        div 2
        <div>div 2.1</div>
        <div>div 2.2</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And I wanted to select with CSS: `div 1 & div 2`, I used:

```
body div:nth-of-type(1) {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}

body div:nth-child(2) {
    background: blue;
}
```

But  `div 2.1 & 2.21` got selected too. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yjvqtr0p/6/)

Is it possible to do a non recursive selection? If not I guess the only solution are clases or id's..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put a `>` between `body` and `div` to select only **direct** children of `body`:

```css
body > div:nth-of-type(1) {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}

body > div:nth-child(2) {
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div>div 1</div>
    <div>
        div 2
        <div>div 2.1</div>
        <div>div 2.2</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ">" character to indicate a parent-child selector. Since 2.1 and 2.2 by default are transparent this doesn't solve the coloring problem so you should style them differently:

https://jsfiddle.net/evccpeeL/1/

```
div {
    background: white;
}

body > div:nth-of-type(1) {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}

body > div:nth-child(2) {
    background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to use pseudo-classes here.

You can do this with the direct child selector `>` alone

```css
body > div {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
body > div > div {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>div 1</div>
  <div>
    div 2
    <div>div 2.1</div>
    <div>div 2.2</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

You might find this article useful [**The 30 CSS Selectors you Must Memorize**](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

Comment: The article is great, thanks for the doc!